# Не работают сессии PHP (OpenServer)

Tags: php, сессия, openserver

```php
<?php session_start();

        if ($_GET["aa"] == "aa") {
            $_SESSION['answer']['result'] = "WORKING!!"; 
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['answer'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['answer']['result'];
            unset($_SESSION['answer']);
        }
 ?>
```

Собственно есть некий код, и он не работает. ;( Если закомментировать или удалить строку с `unset($_SESSION['answer']);`, то все работает, но с ней ни в какую не срабатывает `echo $_SESSION['answer']['result']`;

Возможно он переадресовывает дважды?!

Comment: Закомментите хедер и будет ехо скорее всего

Answer (score 4):

```
session_start();

if ($_GET["aa"] == "aa") {
    $_SESSION['answer']['result'] = "WORKING!!"; 
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit; // !!!!
}

if (isset($_SESSION['answer'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['answer']['result'];
    unset($_SESSION['answer']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

После header (если вам нужно обновить или перенаправить пользователя) нужно прописывать exit или die, чтобы остановить выполнение скрипта, иначе он сначала полностью отработает, а потом сработает правило из header.